# Definition of Differential Multivariate Function

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I am taking a statistical course recently. The lecturer introduces the definition of differentiation of multivariate function which is :

Def: $F = D \subset \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$, for $x \in int(D)$ and $\forall \ h \in \mathbb{R}^n$, if $\exists \ A(x) \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ such that
$$\lim_{h\rightarrow \infty} \frac{\|F(x+h) - F(x) - A(x)h\|}{\|h\|} = 0,$$
then $F(x)$ is differential at $x$ and $F'(x) = A(x)$.

The lecturer did not explain the reason of the definition. According to single variable case, the definition of the differential function is $\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}$ instead of $\infty$. Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possibly simple typo. Did you ask him/her about?

Comment: @zkutch No, in the following lectures the lecturer uses this definition to prove some theorems.

Comment: @zkutch In you opinion, what is the right form?

Comment: Rudin W. - Principles of mathematical analysis-(1976) page 212, Spivak Michael - Calculus On Manifolds (2018) page 16, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_derivative and so on.. very long list with same definition. Can you share your source?

Comment: Agree with @zkutch. It's definitely $h\to0$.

Comment: @zkutch The lecturer writes the lecture notes by hand, I dont know the source. Let me ask this question next time. Thanks